# redmine upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

at the moment I want to upgrade redmine 1.4.0 to the latest version 2.0.2.

So I followed the howto on this page:

```
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade
```

In short I downloaded the redmine-source and extracted it in a separate folder
    "/var/www/redmine-2.0.2" 
(whereas my working installation is in /var/www/redmine).

up to Step 3.5 everything went fine but in 3.6
the following happens:

```
root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2# rake config/initializers/session_store.rb
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'config/initializers/session_store.rb'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2# rake --trace     
config/initializers/session_store.rb
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'config/initializers/session_store.rb'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-
0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-   
0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-
0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake   - 
0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-
0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-
0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake- 
0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-
0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-
0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-
0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top 
(required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2#

root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2# rake --trace generate_session_store
Invoke generate_session_store (first_time)
Invoke generate_secret_token (first_time)
Invoke config/initializers/secret_token.rb (first_time)
Execute config/initializers/secret_token.rb
Execute generate_secret_token
Execute generate_session_store
Note: The rake task generate_session_store has been deprecated, please use the         
replacement version generate_secret_token
root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2#

root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2# rake generate_session_store

Note: The rake task generate_session_store has been deprecated, please use the 
replacement version generate_secret_token

root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2# rake --trace generate_secret_token
Invoke generate_secret_token (first_time)
Invoke config/initializers/secret_token.rb (first_time, not_needed)
Execute generate_secret_token
```

this last step seems to generate "/var/www/redmine-2.0.2/config/initializers/secret_token.rb"
and according to the how to it is a sufficient substitute to the "rake-commands" before.

```
root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2# 
root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2# rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production 
root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2# rake tmp:cache:clear
root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2# rake tmp:sessions:clear
```

My first prob is how to start the application. I can still go to my old installation "/var/www/redmine" 
and start with

```
ruby ./script/server -e production &
```

which still works, the output is:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-
2.3.14/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated  
in the future, use String#encode instead.
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.14 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after     
2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rails-
2.3.14/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

But I can't start the application by going to the new folder "/var/www/redmine-2.0.2/"
and calling

```
ruby ./script/server -e production &
```

because there is no file

```
"/var/www/redmine-2.0.2/script/server".
```

How can I start the updated version of redmine or is not possible yet ?
I think redmine 2.0.2 needs rails 3.2.5 and I thought I installed
it because:

```
root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2/script# rails -v
Rails 3.2.5
root(at)information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2/script#
```

According to the boot protocol above Rails 2.3.14 is used. Wrong ?

Whats my mistake here ? Can somebody give advice howto 
succesfully upgrade ?

thanks for your help in advance!

Cheers,

Ansgar

Answer (score 1):

Solve it by using `bundle exec rails s -d -e production` to start the application in background using the default port (i.e. 3000).

## Update

It seems to be an RVM issue, if you open a new shell and running:

```
$ type rvm | head -1
```

does not show "rvm is a function", RVM isn't being sourced correctly.

Ensure that RVM is sourced after any path settings as RVM and manipulates the path. If you don't do this, RVM may not work as expected.

Comment: root@information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2# bundle exec rails s -d -e production &
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.3/lib/json/ext/parser.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i486-linux]


[1]+  Abgebrochen             bundle exec rails s -d -e production
root@information:/var/www/redmine-2.0.2#

Comment: Thank you! ... but I had Segmentation fault:
# bundle exec rails s -d -e  --trace production &
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:63:in `require': no such file to load -- rack/handler/production (LoadError)

Comment: There is something strange in your environment you are using a ruby interpreter 1.8.7-p302 with a rvm gemset for ruby 1.9.3-p194. I think that rvm is not fully loaded in your shell. BTW about your question that is the command you need to run. Just check your rvm installation.

Comment: What's the output of `ruby -v`?

Comment: "ruby -v" yields "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]"

Comment: That's strange, and what is the output of `bundle exec ruby -v`. In my opinion there is an issue with your RVM configuration.

Comment: Hi! ... that was it ...I got my redmine running now! Thanks a lot! I'm really new to the ruby stuff. I linked another ruby with the 'ln -s command' which is of course bullshit. Now I use "gem" and it worked. 'rails -v' now yields rails Rails 2.3.14. But that does not bothers me... You helped me a lot!